# How to retrieve the elements of array objects

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to add the objects into an array and i'm getting the output like object format in alert box.
so how can i get the data in string format.

```
selectDocFile(event: any) {
    let files = event.target.files;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      var element = {};
      element["id"] = i;
      element["name"] = files.name;
      this.selectedDocumentFiles.push({ element: element });
      alert(this.selectedDocumentFiles);
    }
  }
```

Comment: have you tried putting alert outside of the loop?

Comment: Yeah i tried but i didn't get the result ..in that alert function i'm just accessing the array i don't know how to access object of array.

Comment: Try to use `alert(JSON.stringify(this.selectedDocumentFiles));`

Comment: object of array? or array of object ?

Comment: if array of object, you can try by declaring an array variable outside the loop. Say let `arr = []` then inside the loop, you can `arr.push({ id: i, name: files.name })`. Then the alert function goes outside the loop, too: `alert(arr)`

Comment: `selectDocFile(event: any) { let files = event.target.files var element = [] for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) { element.push({ id: i, name: files.name }) } alert(element) }`

Comment: Thank you @uminder but i'm not expecting the result in JSON format..i wanna access the array objects in loop..so that's why i used the alert function to test the result.

Comment: Yes @Karma Blackshaw. but here you inserting the object inside the array and you declared the array name in alert fun. so then it will returns the object only .. then how to access the object of that arry ?..i mean i want to display object id in alert box in your given example.

Comment: to display the object, you can specify the index. `alert(arr[index])`.

Comment: I got the result @Karma Blackshaw...thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your array declaration outside of the loop as well as your alert function like so:

```
selectDocFile (event: any) {
  let files = event.target.files
  let element = []
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    element.push({ id: i, name: files.name })
  }
  alert(element)
}
```

To alert a single object from the array, you can call the index of the array, like so:

```
alert(element[index])
```

Comment: thank you Karma it's working and i did the code format like this - selectDocFile(event: any) {
    let files = event.target.files;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      var element = { id: i, name: files[i].name, path: files[i] };
      this.selectedDocumentFiles.push(element);
    }
    // alert(JSON.stringify(this.selectedDocumentFiles));
    this.selectedDocumentFiles.forEach(({ id, name }) => alert(`fileid- ${id}, filename- ${name}`));
  }

Answer (score 0):

You **missed** to take **`index of file`** in the **array**.

**`files[i].name`** instead of **`files.name`**

**`element["name"] = files[i].name;`**

```
selectDocFile(event: any) {
    let files = event.target.files;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      var element = {};
      element["id"] = i;
      element["name"] = files[i].name;
      this.selectedDocumentFiles.push({ element: element });
      alert(JSON.stringify(this.selectedDocumentFiles));
    }
  }
```

Also, while alerting, to display in string format, use `JSON.stringify()`

**`alert(JSON.stringify(this.selectedDocumentFiles));`**

Comment: thank you Sravan it's working and i did the code format like this - selectDocFile(event: any) {
    let files = event.target.files;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      var element = { id: i, name: files[i].name, path: files[i] };
      this.selectedDocumentFiles.push(element);
    }
    // alert(JSON.stringify(this.selectedDocumentFiles));
    this.selectedDocumentFiles.forEach(({ id, name }) => alert(`fileid- ${id}, filename- ${name}`));
  }

Comment: glad to help you. You can upvote and accept my answer, if you find it useful.